# LIDAR data for Chicago

Tags: data, lidar, footprint

Is there any public or private sources of LIDAR data for the city of Chicago? Searching online has not lead me to any sources, and I am unsure how the commercial world of LIDAR works.

The LIDAR point spacing would need to be at an interval that I can use to estimate the building height from the [footprints](http://data.cityofchicago.org/Government/Boundaries-Buildings/w2v3-isjw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does Chicago belong to a council of governments? Often a COG facilitates LiDAR contracts by pooling together funds from participating municipalities. Otherwise you might try the City of Chicago's GIS department: GISTeam@cityofchicago.org

Answer (score 1):

Another source is Cook County which has lidar.

Comment: How/where can the Cook County LiDAR data be accessed/found?